# Run website on IIS in server with Windows Admin Center installed

Tags: ssl, iis

I have Windows Server 2019 Standard which I have enabled IIS. Also on the same server I have installed `Windows Admin Center`.

I want to add a site which this must run with `https` on default port `443`.

I created a new site and set protocol to `https` choose `ip` of the server as binding and let the default port of `443`. Also I choose a certificate from the dropdown list of certificates.

Now when I want to run the site I get to the `Windows Admin Center` application because it is on the same port `443`. Can I change it without installing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Later I uninstalled it and it's the same error. I can't find how to release `443` port.

Per Microsoft, [if you previously had Windows Admin Center installed, and now nothing else can use the same TCP/IP port](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/support/troubleshooting#i-previously-had-windows-admin-center-installed-and-now-nothing-else-can-use-the-same-tcpip-port), try running:

```
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443
netsh http delete urlacl url=https://+:443/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't run two web application on the same IP, port and hostname. If you can't have different IP and port then change the host header of one of the application.

Comment: I know that. I tried to to stop Windows Admin center Service and I got `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.` error. Later I uninstalled it and it's the same error. I can't find how to release `443` port.